# Unhandled JS Exception: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and getting an error "this.setState is not a function". please help me to figure this out.

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.facebookLogin = this.facebookLogin.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        ready: false,
        email:'',
       name:''
      }
}


facebookLogin = () =>{
      LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile','email']).then(function(result){
        if(result.isCancelled){
            console.log('loging cancelled')
        }
        else {
            console.log('login success' + result.grantedPermissions)
            const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
                parameters: {
                    'fields': {
                        'string' : 'email,name'
                    }
                }
            },function(error, result) {
              console.log(result)
              if (error) {
                alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
              } else {
                this.setState({name: result.name, email:result.email});
              }});
            new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.log('An error occured: ' + error)
    })
    }
```

**this.setState({name: result.name, email:result.email}); **

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnfb} 
                     onPress={this.facebookLogin}>
             <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey your code seems to be missing the class declaration. Can you please add it?
I assume the second piece of code is part of your render function? 
Is facebookLogin part of the class the constructor creates?

Comment: Can you edit your question so its clearer? Where exactly is this.setState being called?

Comment: this.setState is called inside of the callback , function(error, result) {} .... replace it with (error, result) => { .... } or move it to a separate method that you bind(this) inside the constructor

Answer (score 4):

Every time you declare a function like `function () {}` it creates a new scope, so by the time you get to setState, `this` is no longer your component.

A quick fix is to use arrow functions: `() => {}` since it keeps the scope, or passing `this` from the outer scope into where you need it thru a variable.

Answer (score 1):

setState that you are trying to access is available in your class scope. However you are calling setstate in a function scope called by some action of yours. As a solution to your problem you need to bind this along with your function in onpress action i.e. this.facebooklogin.bind(this). So this way you have access to this of class scope in your function. You can store this in another variable in the function and use that to call setState.

Alternatively you can use ES6 arrow function to solve this issue.